# How can I make a function that repeats till it gets to a result without several requests?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm doing a memory game and I need to don't repeat the same picture more than twice, so I made a random number generator that repeats till the number isn't in an array. Doing that makes so many requests, so, when repeating the code, it doesn't work so I can't make the second half of the game. I know that the problem is in that because, when making it return the result without checking if it isn't in the array, everything works (but the images repeat, obviously). So, how can I make a function that gives a random number between two values that isn't in an array? I hope this is easy to understand.

Here the function:

```
function thingForTest() {
      let forTest = randomBetweenBut(1, 8, 0);
      if (array.includes(forTest)) {
        return thingForTest();
      } else {
        return forTest;
      }
    }
```

Here the entire code:

```
var array = [];

function randomBetweenBut(num1, num2, but) {
  function ifThing(num1, num2, but) {
    let result = parseInt(Math.random() * (num2 - num1 + 1), 10) + num1;
    if (result != but) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return ifThing(num1, num2, but);
    }
  }
  return ifThing(num1, num2, but);
}
function pictureRandomizer() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
    let r1;
    let picture = document.createElement("img");

    function thingForTest() {
      let forTest = randomBetweenBut(1, 8, 0);
      if (array.includes(forTest)) {
        return thingForTest();
      } else {
        return forTest;
      }
    }

    array.push(thingForTest());
    picture.src = "img/" + array[i - 1] + ".jpg";
    let cuadrado = document.getElementById("cuadrado-" + i);
    cuadrado.appendChild(picture);
    if(i == 16 && r1 == false) {
        i = 1;
        r1 = true;
    } else {
        r1 = false;
    }
  }
}
pictureRandomizer();
```

Comment: what if you have an shuffled array and count how many elements you have returned, so in each turn just increment counter and return a new element from the array???

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea. Thank you. I will test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this to return a random number between a min and a max, excluding any number passed in the exclusionArray. No recursion needed! It also includes a clause to stop infinite loops when a complete exclusionArray is passed.

Should be noted that since we're rerolling a random function, this could loop infinitely if you got REALLY unlucky, so this may not be the best function if your min, max and exclusionArray length are in the millions; But for most applications this should get the job done.

```
const getRandomWithExclusion = (min, max, exclusionArray) => {

  // if exculsionArray contains all possible integers, return null to avoid infinite loop
  if (exclusionArray.length > max - min) return null;

  let output = null;

  // if the randomly generated number is in the exclusionArray, reroll
  while(output === null || exclusionArray.includes(output)) {
    // simple random range function
    output = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }

  return output;

}
```

.....

Comment: but is Math.round